NetworkManager: Connection activation failed: (5) IP configuration could not be reserved (no available address, timeout, etc.)
I've tried to connect to a TP Link extender via Network Manager on Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS but 4h later I still hit the same wall.
It connects for a while initially and then disconnects completely.
Switching between dhclient and dhcpcd didn't help.
I struggle to understand what's the real cause of it.
Other devices can connect with no problems.
Connecting via Network Manager gui results with:

Wireless Interface wlp5s0
IP configuration was unavailable

nmcli device wifi  connect 'NOS-B926_EXT' password '<>'
Error: Connection activation failed: (5) IP configuration could not be reserved (no available address, timeout, etc.).

The last journal logs are:
NetworkManager[1110]: <info>  [1731865495.7982] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
NetworkManager[1110]: <info>  [1731865495.8677] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
NetworkManager[1110]: <info>  [1731865495.8678] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: associating-> associated
NetworkManager[1110]: <info>  [1731865496.0118] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
NetworkManager[1110]: <info>  [1731865496.0119] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
NetworkManager[1110]: <info>  [1731865496.0456] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
NetworkManager[1110]: <info>  [1731865496.0458] device (wlp5s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "NOS-B926_EXT"
NetworkManager[1110]: <info>  [1731865496.0459] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
NetworkManager[1110]: <info>  [1731865496.0464] device (wlp5s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[1110]: <info>  [1731865496.0483] dhcp4 (wlp5s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
NetworkManager[1110]: <info>  [1731865541.2298] device (wlp5s0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[1110]: <info>  [1731865541.2308] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
NetworkManager[1110]: <warn>  [1731865541.2321] device (wlp5s0): Activation: failed for connection 'NOS-B926_EXT'
NetworkManager[1110]: <info>  [1731865541.2329] device (wlp5s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[1110]: <info>  [1731865541.2399] dhcp4 (wlp5s0): canceled DHCP transaction
NetworkManager[1110]: <info>  [1731865541.5196] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
NetworkManager[1110]: <info>  [1731865541.5197] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether <> brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp5s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether <> brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Running dhclient:
sudo dhclient wlp5s0 -v
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/wlp5s0/<>
Sending on   LPF/wlp5s0/<>
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.1.101 on wlp5s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x47b98c2c)
DHCPACK of 192.168.1.101 from 192.168.1.1 (xid=0x2c8cb947)
Error: ipv4: Address already assigned.
bound to 192.168.1.101 -- renewal in 258240 seconds.

My network adapter:
*-network
description: Wireless interface
product: Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
logical name: wlp5s0
version: 99
serial: <>
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.8.0-47-lowlatency firmware=29.4063824552.0 7265D-29.ucode ip=192.168.55.71 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
resources: irq:149 memory:f1100000-f1101fff

uname -r
6.8.0-47-lowlatency

Please help.
